# get_absolute_url() django docs example returns syntax error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have this model:

```
class Invite(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    cookie = models.SlugField()
    token = models.SlugField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s's invite" % (self.user)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return (reverse('invite'), args=[self.token])
```

The final line, `return (reverse('invite'), args=[self.token])`, returns a syntax error. When I remove the `args=` part, it seems to work fine though.

I have three questions regarding this:

1. Why is `arg=` in this example returning a syntax error while the django docs uses a similiar example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_absolute_url).
2. How am I supposed to successfully key into this list/check the contents of the list without assigning it a name?
3. Does `return` require `()` to work with more than one variable? Since im using python 2.7.5 wouldn't a simple `,` suffice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the closing parenthesis in the wrong place. `args` is an argument to `reverse`.

```
return (reverse('invite', args=[self.token]))
```

Comment: Thanks. But why can't it be `return (reverse('invite'), args=[self.token])`? Shouldn't that work, too?

Comment: No, why should it? As I said, `args` is an argument to reverse, which means it has to be inside the calling parentheses for reverse. In fact your outer parentheses do absolutely nothing at all; I should have removed them in my answer.